What do Autoencoders do form a statistical point of view?
As the title suggests, i was wondering how can autoencoders be interpreted from a statistical point of view. Here, i'll try to give you my interpretation but, since i'm not too familiar with statistics, i'd like to know if this interpretation is correct or not.
To recap, autoencoders are composed by two neural networks: the encoder $p(z|x)$, which associate a code (or latent variable) $z\sim p(z|x)$ to the input sample $x$; and a decoder $p(x|z)$, that from the code $z$ is able to reconstruct the input sample $x\sim p(x|z)$.
Training an autoencoder consists in maximizing the following loss function:
$$L = E_{x,y\sim p(x,z)} [\underbrace{p(z|x)}_{encoder}\cdot\underbrace{p(x|z)}_{decoder}]$$
The decoder can be rewritten as $p(z|x)=\frac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}$, as well as the encoder $p(x|z)=\frac{p(z,x)}{p(z)}$. Then, since we are maximizing we can apply the logarithm without changing the maximization problem. Then, using the jensen inequality, we can bring the logarithm inside the expected value, therefore obtaining:
$$L = E_{x,y\sim p(x,z)} [\text{log}(\underbrace{\frac{p(z,x)}{p(z)}}_{encoder}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{p(z,x)}{p(x)})}_{decoder}]$$
By using the property of the logarithms we can split the expected value in two terms:
$$L = \underbrace{E_{x,z\sim p(x,z)} [\text{log } \frac{p(x,z)}{p(x)p(z)}]}_{I(x,z)} + \underbrace{E_{x,z\sim p(x,z)} [\text{log } p(x,z)]}_{H(x,z)}$$
So, the autoencoder, trained to reconstruct the input, tries to find a code (or latent representation) which maximizes the mutual information with the input sample. Secondly, it also tries to maximize the joint entropy between the input sample and the code. Most of the times, the two distribution are not considered probabilistic but deterministic functions, which is equivalent to just getting the argmax of the distribution.
At this point i can further decompose my initial question:

Is what i said correct about autoencoders and the way they are trained. Can they be interpreted in such way form a statistical point of view? if no, what is wrong with my derivation?

If the derivation is correct, I can grasp that the autoencoder is maximizing the mutual information but what about the joint entropy? what is the meaning of that?



They’re used as a practical, adjustable information bottleneck, a kind of dimensional reduction.
